Inclusion of completions of finitely generated $k$-algebras
I have the following question.
Let $A \hookrightarrow B$ be an inclusion of finitely generated $k$-algebras which is neither finite nor flat map (in the first case the answer to the following question is positive), where $k$ is any field, and $\pi\colon \mathrm{Spec}B \rightarrow \mathrm{Spec}A$ be the associated map on spectra. Let $\mathfrak{p}\in \mathrm{Spec}A$, and let $\pi^{-1}(\mathfrak{p}) = \{\mathfrak{P}_i\}_{i\in I}\subset \mathrm{Spec}B$ be the preimage of $\mathfrak{p}$ under $\pi$. For some $i$ consider the natural map
$$A_\mathfrak{p}/\mathfrak{p}^lA_\mathfrak{p}\longrightarrow B_{\mathfrak{P}_i}/\mathfrak{P}_i^lB_{\mathfrak{P}_i},$$
where $A_\mathfrak{p}$ and $B_{\mathfrak{P}_i}$ are localizations by the corresponding ideals.
This map induces a map on completions, and therefore we get
$$\varphi\colon \hat{A}_\mathfrak{p}\longrightarrow\prod_{i\in I}\hat{B}_{\mathfrak{P}_i}.$$
Can $\varphi$ be an inclusion? If we require that both $A$ and $B$ are Noetherian $k$-algebras ($A$ is embedded in $B$ as before) and $B$ is finitely generated over $A$, that can the previous question hold (i.e. we weaken conditions on $A$ and $B$)? If we also require that $A$ and $B$ are integral, can the above question still hold true? Are there any other assumptions for which the above question is true ($A$ is, for example, local and $\mathfrak{p}$ is a maximal ideal, or $B$ is regular)?
My attempts run into the problem of a cofinality of ideal topologies. Namely, it is sufficient to prove that topology generated by ideals $\{\mathfrak{a}_l = \bigcap_{i\in I}(\mathfrak{P}_i^lB_{\mathfrak{P}_i}\cap A_\mathfrak{p})\}_{l=1}^\infty$ and topology generated by ideals $\{\mathfrak{p}^lA_\mathfrak{p}\}_{l=1}^\infty$ are cofinal. From this point of view, it is related to the question about a relation between powers of contraction of ideal and contractions of powers of ideal. One of the known to me results in this area is the relation between symbolic and ordinary powers of ideal in a regular ring.
Any help would be appreciated!
